# Is there a way to hide/remove parts of a fluid sim mesh so they won't show in render?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I have my fluid simulation beneath a floor plane, and I only want the splashes that rise above the plane to be visible in the final render. I've been trying to find a way to make the pool of fluid below the plane invisible, but applying a boolean to the domain didn't work. I don't think an outflow object would work either, as I do need the fluid to be there in order for it to splash.

Is there any method out there for doing this?

Comment: If I understood Boolean should work, tested here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176612/can-we-make-our-fluid-domain-object-from-a-cylinder/181655#181655 probably you should post your simplified blend  via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so we can check

Comment: Thanks for confirming that is the right method. I'm going to take a look at that thread and see if I can figure out what step I missed. I'll post back

Comment: So it does in fact work using a boolean, but not if the fluid mesh has been converted to particles. I thought this was the accepted practice for fluid sims but I'm assuming there's also a way to texture your fluid without going the particle route. I'm going to look into it

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment  and probably for that I don't see a relationship to your original question.

Comment: I meant when you go into the particle settings for the fluid sim and by default it is set to "Halo" which as I understood it would not render. So I set this to "collection", where I have several UV spheres with the material I want. Using this setting,t eh boolean did not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of **Particles System** type **Fluid**, there is not a direct way to hide part of particles. You would have to convert sim to mesh.

In this example I used Metaball as particle (because Icosphere object keeps particle system after export).

- export into Alembic format
- import back and use Boolean Modifier

[image]
[image]

[image]

### EDIT

OK I got it, you mean particles generated by **Fluid Simulation** (Mantaflow) - *Liquid* and *Spray*.

[image]

Yes, particles are not affected by *Boolean Modifier*.
[image]

So there does not exist a way to hide a part of released particles. So only way I know is to use Mball as particle and export-import it as Alembic and use Boolean.
[image]

[image]

---

Note: In theory - to exclude some particles from render you can influent particles size by Texture, so classic particle system can do this, but fluid sim particles doesnt have such feature.